# how to select the info in one raw table

Tags: sql, symfony

hi  i want to select the info by the file link , for example 
in database in first line :

```
file link :  src/java/son3.wav | word : mailing 

secund line in DB : file link : src/java/son3.wav  | word: smtp
3rd line in DB  : file link : src/java/son2.wav | word : server
```

I want to show like this in the html.twig  ::

```
id : 1 | file link : src/java/son3.wav | word : mailing , smtp
id : 2 | file link : src/java/son2.wav | word : server
```

so that select all the words in DB that have the same file link, I hope this explains what I'm after.

I'm using symfony 3.4 
and this is how it showed in my interface :

[image: https://i.imgur.com/9roxlOA.jpg]

this is pic of my table in DB :

[image]

```
this is the code of file twig :

  <table  class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                  <th>File Link</th>
                  <th>Words</th>

              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          {% for result in resultats %}
                <tr>
                  <td><a href="{{ path('result', { 'id': result.id }) }}">{{ result.id }}</a></td>
                  <td>{{ result.indexeFichier.fichierUrl }}</td>
                  <td>{{ result.indexeMot.motValeur }}</td>




              </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
      </table>



and this is the code of file controller :

  public function IndexAction()
    {


      ////////////////////////////////////////////
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $resultats = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Indexe')->findAll();
      return $this->render('userfiles/result.html.twig', array(
          'resultats' => $resultats,
      ));

    }

}
```

Comment: It is possible when relation should be one to many between table  indexeFichier and indexeMot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just condense the results afterward in plain php.

```
$viewResults = [];
foreach ($resultatas as $result) {
    if (!isset($viewResults[$result->getIndexeMot()->getMotValeur())]) {
        $viewResults[$result->getIndexeMot()->getMotValeur()] = ['id' => $result->getId(), 'motValeurs' => []];
    }
    $viewResults[$result->getIndexeMot()->getMotValeur()]['motValeurs'][] = $result->getIndexeFichier()->getFichierUrl();
}
```

And in the view separate them as you like:

```
{% for key, result in resultats %}
<tr>
    <td><a href="{{ path('result', { 'id': result.id }) }}">{{ result.id }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ result.indexeFichier.fichierUrl }}</td>
    <td>
        {% for motValeur in result.motValeurs %}
            {{ result.indexeMot.motValeur }}
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

PS: If you use the Symfony Profiler, you will see that your usage of `findAll()` will probably add two additional queries PER result, because the result is not properly joined. It would be better to store the results directly in `indexe`, or to join the two other tables through a doctrine query: `getRepository(Indexe::class)->createQueryBuilder('q')->join('q.indexeMot', 'm')->join('q.indexeFichier')->getResult();`

Comment: i get a error  like this one : 

Neither the property "motValeurs" nor one of the methods "motValeurs()", "getmotValeurs()"/"ismotValeurs()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Indexe".

Comment: what that mean ??

Comment: what that mean ??